# Loading File directly from Node js req body to S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sails.js

I am trying to upload files to s3 using `Node.js` `Amazon Web Service` sdk and I try to pick file directly from the request body to upload on Amazon. But, I keep getting a `TypeError: buf.copy is not a function`. Below is my code:

```
 create: function(req, res) {
    var imageFile = req.file('imageFile');
    var fileName = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    var key = settings.aws.Key;
    var secret = settings.aws.Secret;
    var bucket = settings.aws.Bucket;
    AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: key, secretAccessKey: secret});
    var parames = {Bucket: bucket, Key: fileName, Body: imageFile};
    var s3Obj = new AWS.S3();
    s3Obj.upload(parames).
    on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {console.log("In "+evt.loaded); }).
    send(function(err, data){
        if (err) {
            return ValidationService.jsonResolveError(err, Inventory, res);
        }
        console.log(data);
        res.json({status:200, file: data});
    })
}
```

And a more detailed stack trace of the error I keep getting:

> buffer.js:237
>       buf.copy(buffer, pos);
>           ^
>
> TypeError: buf.copy is not a function
>       at Function.Buffer.concat (buffer.js:237:9)
>       at ManagedUpload.fillStream (/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/s3/managed_upload.js:389:21)
>       at Upstream. (/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/s3/managed_upload.js:172:28)
>       at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
>       at Upstream.emit (events.js:166:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
>       at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:455:9)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:410:17)

Comment: That's somewhat confusing, but Sails treats all `req.file` calls as streams, meaning there are events and callbacks for when the file is, has and is done uploading etc. you don't seem to use any of them, you just pass `imageFile`, which is not a file, but a buffer, straight to S3's upload handler? FYI: you can upload files to S3 directly from the browser as well, without ever touching your server.

Comment: I know. But, answering asking a question? Looking here http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/request-req/req-file, I see that I can upload a file and it'll be kept temporarily for some time in the `.tmp` I just want to know if it'll be deleted. Cause, looking at my `.tmp` I can see all the tests I've been trying for 3days now. Including those I uploaded using SkipperS3. But, skipper s3 is limited to `s3.amazon.com`

Comment: I have no idea what Sails does internally, but at that link there's an example showing one of the event handlers, and how you need to wait for the file to actually upload before you can send it other places.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. Now I get it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `req.file('imageFile')` returns, but you should set a stream to AWS.S3 params' Body field.
Something like:

```
var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
fileStream.on('open', () => {
    //your existing S3 initialisation code...
     var parames = {Bucket: bucket, Key: fileName, Body: fileStream};
```

Comment: `req.file('imageFile')` is the parameter being passed from `sails req` so, it points to the multipart param in it body. I don't want to upload to my server first before uploading to s3

Comment: I see...well, I think one way or another, it will be uploaded indirectly to your server - perhaps not on disk, but in memory. Anyway, checking sails 'file' docs, I noticed that .file(...:) returns a stream in 'object mode'. I think the 'object mode' stream might be the issue you're having. Here's from the sails docs "Normally, Streams operate on Strings and Buffers exclusively. Streams that are in object mode can emit generic JavaScript values other than Buffers and Strings."

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Node 8 you can make use of async/await and stream a file from local directory to S3 as follows:

```
async function uploadFile(filePath, folderPath)
{
  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

  const writeStream = new stream.PassThrough();
  readStream.pipe(writeStream);

  var fname = path.basename(filePath);

  var params = {
        Bucket : 's3-bucket-name',
        Key : folderPath+'/'+fname,
        Body : writeStream
    }

  let uploadPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        //logger.error('upload error..', err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        //logger.debug('upload done..');
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  });

  var res = await uploadPromise;
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Yeah. Thank you.

Did that in 2016. I already forgot about the post.